# Why does my simple string vulnerability program segfault, and how do I avoid?

Tags: c

I'm trying to do myself a little string formatting vulnerability exercise.
I have this c code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int target;
int main()
{
    char string[20];

    printf("Enter your password:\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%[^\n]", string);
   printf(string);
  
  if(target) {
      printf("you have modified the target :)\n");
  }
}
```

That I compile:

```
gcc format.c -o form -no-pie -fno-stack-protector
```

And now I should be able to insert `%x` to get leaks:

```
$ ./form
Enter your password:
%x %x %x %x %x %x %x
a 0 0 a 7c 25207825 20782520
```

This works, but I need to leak a lot of memory, so I go on:

```
$ ./form
Enter your password:
%x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

and it segfaults. Which none of the online tutorials does, even though they do the same, and I have disabled some protections also.

How can I do this without running into this segfault isse?

Comment: Writing past the bounds of an array is *undefined behavior*, your (and whatever resources you consulted) assumption that it *will* overwrite `target` is simply incorrect

Comment: `string` and `target` are totally unrelated. One is on the stack, the other on the heap.

Comment: Your target is not initialised so your code may not be accurate.

Comment: @PtitXav `target` is initialised to `0`.

Comment: fflush(stdin) is undefined behavior, scanf is error prone to use with input, use instead fgets then sscanf. always check return values of functions, scanf returns something, check it out

Comment: @WeatherVane : target may usually be set to 0 by compiler but it may not always be like this.

Comment: @PtitXav `target` is global static variable, not an automatic one, so it is *always* initialised to 0 by every conforming compiler.

Comment: @WeatherVane : thanks , I did not know.